# How does YDN handle private browsing?

Tags: ydn-db

Firefox disables IndexedDB in private browsing.  Does YDN fallback to another mechanism in that case?  We are getting InvalidStateErrors which tell me that it just fails.

If that's the case, is there a way we can get force YDN to use a different mechanism?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should automatically select suitable storage mechanism in private browsing.

To change storage mechanism, use [`mechanisms`](http://dev.yathit.com/api/ydn/db/storage.html) options as follow:

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('db name', null, {mechanisms: ['memory']});
```

Edit: 2016 Nov

IndexedDB is available (but not persist) in Chrome incognito mode. Firefox [is working to make IndexedDB available](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781982) in private mode.

Comment: The problem is how does the code *know* to manually choose the `memory` mechanism?

Comment: YDN-DB can be used in private browsing, but localStorage will be chose since they are available.